# How to attach Python code to exe file

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I made a login panel, but i don't know, how to attach code to files,
for example, if i run a .exe file, it runs my code first, and if the entries are filled correctly, the .exe file runs.
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import os`


username = 'Zsolti'
password = 'zsoltika2005'

def WindowVariables():
    global UsernameE
    global PasswordE

def CheckLogin():
    if UsernameE.get() == username and PasswordE.get() == password:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Login', 'Successfully logged in as: 
Zsolti')
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Login', 'Login failed')

window = Tk()

MainFrame = Frame(width=110, height=40)
MainFrame.grid()

window.title('Login Panel')

UsernameL = Label(window, text='Enter username')
UsernameL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')

PasswordL = Label(window, text='Enter password')
PasswordL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')

UsernameE = Entry(window, textvariable=username)
UsernameE.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')

PasswordE = Entry(window, show='*', textvariable=password)
PasswordE.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

LoginButton = Button(window, text='Login!', command=CheckLogin)
LoginButton.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: add more context for us to understand what do you meant by attached code to `exe` file you want to convert it to `executable` or what .

Comment: At a guess you want to click on your application, It verifies a logon, and then runs the main application? if so you would have your program do its thing, then something like "import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r"U:\Year 8\kerbal space program\KSP.exe"])" to open the main application, To wrap it all up with a bow, you could use Pyinstaller to compile your python program so its just and .exe to open yours and it will call the existing exe

Comment: @Reroute yes
if i run a .exe the panel pops up firstly, and if i fill the entry widgets correctly, it runs the target application

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, when it logs on correctly, it will call the other exe file, then hopefully terminate the login window,

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import subprocess
import sys


username = 'Zsolti'
password = 'zsoltika2005'


def WindowVariables():
    global UsernameE
    global PasswordE


def CheckLogin():
    if UsernameE.get() == username and PasswordE.get() == password:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Login', 'Successfully logged in as: Zsolti')
        subprocess.Popen([r"Important File Path.exe"])
        sys.exit()
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Login', 'Login failed')


window = Tk()

MainFrame = Frame(width=110, height=40)
MainFrame.grid()

window.title('Login Panel')

UsernameL = Label(window, text='Enter username')
UsernameL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')

PasswordL = Label(window, text='Enter password')
PasswordL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')

UsernameE = Entry(window, textvariable=username)
UsernameE.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')

PasswordE = Entry(window, show='*', textvariable=password)
PasswordE.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

LoginButton = Button(window, text='Login!', command=CheckLogin)
LoginButton.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```